# Url Rewriting Regex - no match

Tags: java, regex, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have this regex for an url rewriting:

```
<from>^/page/([0-9]+)/order/(.*)/by/(.*)/composition/(.*)/location/(.*)/price_min/(.*)/price_max/(.*)/industry/(.*)/type/(.*)$</from>
<to>/page=$1&order=$2&by=$3&composition=$4&location_id=$5&price_min=$6&price_max=$7&industry_id=$8&type_id=$9</to>
```

I want to match an URL like the below one, but there is no match.

> /page/2/order/id/by/desc/composition/1/location/none/price_min/2/price_max/2/industry/2/type/3

Comment: Try replacing the greedy `.*` with the non-greedy `.*?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the following one:

```
^/page/([0-9]+)/order/(.+?)/by/(.+?)/composition/(.+?)/location/(.+?)/price_min/(.+?)/price_max/(.+?)/industry/(.+?)/type/(.+?)$
```

Two things with your regex:

1. You should be using `.+` instead of `.*`, since there will always be data between `/` and `/`.
2. You should add `?`, which means that it will be non-greedy. It is the equivalent as writing `([^/]+)` instead, which means **match any character multiple except `/` multiple times**.

Comment: Oh ok thank you i understand it better now, i'm gonna try this later today

Comment: ok it's working fine thank you, i just added one more thing the & should be an &amp;